# How to Get Random Array From Case

Tags: bash

I tried to get random array in bash 
I used the following code:

```
agents=$(shuf $DISTR)
    case $DISTR in 
        "1")
            echo "amos"
    ;;
        "2")
            echo "dia"
    ;;
        "3")
            echo "dia lagi"
    ;;
esac

echo "$agents"
```

But I am getting the blank result.
Can anyone help me?

i want the output is one of the case

Comment: Do you mean "get a random array *entry*"? Then there are two problems. (1) `agents` is not an array. Use `agents=($(shuf "$DISTR"))` to create one. (2) The switch case statement as no effect on the array. You have to pick a random index and use the index to retrieve an element from the array.

Comment: i need a random output from this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Assumption

`$DISTR` is a path of a non-empty file.

## Fix Existing Code

```
agents=($(shuf "$DISTR")) # create shuffled array
echo "${agents[0]}"       # print the first entry
```

The first entry is a random entry since the array was shuffled.

Note that this solution does only work well for files with one word (no whitespace) per line. If a line contains more than one word, each word will be stored in a separate array entry *after* the lines are shuffled. For a file with the lines

```
...
first second
1st 2nd
...
```

we may print `first` or `1st`, but never `second` or `2nd`.

## Better Solution

Shuffling the complete array is a lot of work if you are only interested in *one* random entry. It is faster to read the array in its original order and pick a random index.

```
mapfile agents "$DISTR"            # create array
length=${#agents[@]}               
randomIndex=$(( RANDOM % length )) # random number between 0 and length-1
echo "${agents[randomIndex]}"
```

Or in short

```
mapfile agents "$DISTR"
echo "${agents[RANDOM % ${#agents[@]}]}"
```

`RANDOM` is a built-in variable/function returns a pseudo-random number (do not use for encryption and so on). `mapfile` stores one line per array entry, even if the lines contain whitespace.

## Best Solution

Again we did too much work. Why read the whole file into an array when we could pick just one random line? (Typical case of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

```
shuf -n 1 "$DISTR" # print one random line
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate random numbers with bash use the $RANDOM internal Bash function. Note that $RANDOM should not be used to generate an encryption key. $RANDOM is generated by using your current process ID (PID) and the current time/date as defined by the number of seconds elapsed since 1970.

```
$(( ( RANDOM % 10 )  + 3 ))
```

Comment: can you fix it ? i need random result from this code. thank you